# strange issue in connection string from visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, webforms, connection

Hi I am not able to connect I get an error server was not found, the problem is my connection string in the data source property in web config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbHolaStaffConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=dbHolaStaff;user id=xx;password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

I have chnaged the source in many ways but cant get it work.

DESKTOP-VNAJJMF\SQL2016
.\SQL2016
localhost\SQL2016

The server name in sql management studio is: DESKTOP-VNAJJMF\SQL2016

My user id and passwords are correct, how can I fix this problem? I dont know why visual studios keeps showing that error.
I also have enabled Remote access in sql server but nothing works.

Comment: Do those server names work when you connect via SQL Management Studio?

also try (local)

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message and stack trace ?

Comment: Can you connect to sql server database from visual studio in server explorer and copy the connectionstring from properties?

Comment: thank you ver much to everyone it was a visual studio problem i guess, i just restarted visual studio and now it works.

Comment: soy un puto dawn de dawns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the below one

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbHolaStaffConnectionString" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-VNAJJMF\SQL2016;Database=dbHolaStaff;user id=xx;password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: hey thank you very much, it was a visual studio problem i guess, i just restarted visual studio and now it works.

Comment: soy un dawnasd as